# jquery: only show one div when hover

Tags: jquery, hover, show

Hey guys, i'm having a problem with this little script. When i hover over the div "item" both divs shows the "dark-overlay". But i only want the dark-overlay there's inside the div i hover to show. How is that possible? thanks :)

---

```
.item {
position:relative;
width:680px;
height:140px;
}
.dark-overlay {
position:absolute;
width:680px;
height:140px;
background:url(images/bg.png) repeat;
display:none;
}
```

---

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="dark-overlay"></div>
   <img src="my image.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="item">
   <div class="dark-overlay"></div>
   <img src="my image.jpg" />
</div>
```

---

```
$(function() {
   $(".item").hover(function() {
      $(".dark-overlay").show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the `.dark-overlay` only inside the one you're hovering, like this:

```
$(function() {
   $(".item").hover(function() {
      $(this).find(".dark-overlay").show();
   });
});
```

Or, more likely, you want it to hide when leaving as well, in which case you should use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like this:

```
$(function() {
   $(".item").hover(function() {
      $(this).find(".dark-overlay").toggle();
   });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xsxfr/), or add a bit of a fade animation, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xsxfr/1/).

Comment: Can you also tell me how i fade the .dark-overlay out when i don't hover the .item? :)

Comment: @Sebastian - check out the demos at the bottom of the answer :)

Comment: Do note that this example uses jQuery 1.4.2. If you're using 1.3.2 the behaviour is a little different. I think the difference lies in the .hover() property but I'm not sure what they changed.

Comment: @Litso - This is the same in 1.3.2, under the covers the event model changed a bit for *other* reasons, but nothing that affects this :)

Comment: @Nick Craver, set the jQuery version in your jFiddle example to 1.3.2 and see what happens. In Chrome at least it does make a big difference.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, the hover event handler takes two arguments (mouse in and mouse out), then just limit the .dark-overlay search to items within "this" (the current .item element)

```
$('.item').hover(
  function() { // Mouse in
    $('.dark-overlay', this ).fadeIn();
  },
  function() { // Mouse out
    $('.dark-overlay', this ).fadeOut();
  }
);
```